# Text area not updating properly, missing characters

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, textarea

I'm trying to update my text area via ActionScript code using this:

```
scoreLabel.text = this.score.toString();
```

but it's not behaving correctly. When the score is `18`, the text area displays just `1`, when it's `26` it won't display anything at all...

As a test, I tried doing this:

```
scoreLabel.text = "this is a test";
```

and now the text area is just displaying `e`:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Yg1I.png

This isn't a font issue, as I'm using Arial. What is going on here?

Comment: I can offer personalised help rather than you having to post so many questions and waiting for replies all day.

Comment: Sometimes TextFields get cut off too. Set textField.border=true; to make sure it's the size you are expecting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you've *embedded* all of the characters you will be using. Assuming just numeric characters, the interface presented when you click "Embed" should look something like this:

[image]

Characters that are in the field when compiled will be embedded, and characters that aren't embedded won't render.